# How to While loop timer in here?

Tags: python, loops, timer, pysimplegui

I have a GUI app with a while loop. I'm having trouble inserting an if statement that breaks the loop. I want this to be a timer so if nothing happens in 60 seconds the while loop will break.

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Velg mappe som skal tas backup av og hvor du vil plassere backupen')],
          [sg.Text('Source folder', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(a), sg.FolderBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('Backup destination ', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(b), sg.FolderBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('Made by XXX™')],
          [sg.Submit("Kjør"), sg.Cancel("Exit")]]
window = sg.Window('Backup Runner v2.1')
```

```
while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Layout(layout).Read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        sys.exit("aa! errors!")
        print("Skriptet ble stoppet")
    if event == 'Kjør':
        window.Close()
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow this link to the docs: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/#persistent-window-example-running-timer-that-updates

You will see that you can use the built-in `time` module to tell you what the time is now. You could calculate the end time and just wait til then:

```
import time

layout = ...
window = sg.Window('Backup Runner v2.1').Layout(layout)

end_time = time.time() + 60

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read(timeout=10)
    # Your usual event handling ...

    if time.time() > end_time:
        break
```

Comment: You should not be calling window.Layout inside of your event loop.  It should be called only one time.  In your event loop, the call should be window.Read(timeout=10).  You can specify the layout in the call to Window itself. It's the second parameter.

Comment: Ok, having re-read the docs (I don't know this framework at all), I'll update my answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with time module:

```
import time

seconds = int(time.time()) # This is seconds since epoch
while True:
    if int(time.time()) > seconds + 60: # True when seconds + 60 < current seconds
        break # End of your loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in PySimpleGUI to do this is to set the `timeout` value in the call to `window.Read()`.

This code will wait for user input for 60 seconds.  If none is received, then you will get a "Timeout Key" value returned to you from the `Read` call.

Note that you should not be calling Layout inside of your while loop.  This is more like what you need:

```
while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read(timeout=60*1000)
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        sys.exit("aa! errors!")
        print("Skriptet ble stoppet")
    if event == 'Kjør':
        window.Close()
        break
    if event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:
        break
```